# Trying to publish my WCF Service to use with Rest

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

Im trying to publish my web services using IIS and there seems to be a problem with my web.config. I want to ultimatly publish my web services to a web host I have. I allready tried publishing the normal file system and uploading thos files to the webhost but I cant seem to get my service.svc to respond. Im thinking its because of my web.config here is the code. If you need anything else of my code please ask :D. Just as a note. The services work just fine when I run them with Visual Studio 2012. Also Im new at this, this is the first time I try to do this. :D

Web.config

```
<configuration> 
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="HotelLock.Service1">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="HotelLock.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" > 
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I uploaded the svc, the web.config and the bin with the dll to a host I have and all I get when I call the svc is

`ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="HotelLock.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs"`

I cant seem to call any of the other urls.

When I tried to use the IIS to use my service as localhost, the page does not load. I allready gave permition for the iis to use the webconfig. But I cant seem to get a normal error. I just cant load anything.

Comment: There appears to be something wrong with your question - did intend to post the error message at the bottom? 'Cause you should.

Comment: When I uploead the files to a host I have and call the services on any rest console there is a 404 error. But if I call the Service1.svc all it shows me is this:
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="HotelLock.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>

Answer (score 0):

The config file looks OK. Maybe you should check the link that you call through the browser. The link should be like the following one:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/ServiceName.ClassName.svc/UriTemplate
```

For your project, I think service name is HotelLock and the classname is Service1. I don't know the UriTemplate of your code but your interface (probably IService.cs) should have that information (e.g. [WebGet(UriTemplate = "ListData")]) Finally, your link looks like  http://www.yourdomain.com/HotelLock.Service1.svc/ListData

I hope it works.